# UPDATEXML throws SQL Error: ORA-00927: missing equal sign when attempting to convert and update CLOB datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I worked through the example through the Oracle documentation page for the **UPDATEXML** function:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm

Now, I'm trying to apply this to the data in my database. The column in my database is **CLOB** (used for multiple things), so I need to convert my data to the xmltype before performing xml related operations. However, my attempt is returning the following error `SQL Error: ORA-00927: missing equal sign`.

Is there a way to update the clob-stored xml without modifying the column data type?

---

#### Attempt

Reusing the Oracle example with datatypes of my database.
**1. Creating table**

```
CREATE TABLE xwarehouses
(  
  MSD_ID INTEGER,
  CDATA CLOB
);
```

**2. Adding data**

```
INSERT INTO xwarehouses VALUES 
  (1,
  ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <Warehouse>
    <WarehouseId>1</WarehouseId>
    <WarehouseName>Southlake, Texas</WarehouseName>
    <Building>Owned</Building>
    <Area>25000</Area>
    <Docks>2</Docks>
    <DockType>Rear load</DockType>
    <WaterAccess>true</WaterAccess>
    <RailAccess>N</RailAccess>
    <Parking>Street</Parking>
    <VClearance>10</VClearance>
   </Warehouse>'));
```

**3. Converting CLOB to XMLTYPE to extract value from specified tag**

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(cdata),'/Warehouse/WaterAccess') as VAL from xwarehouses;
```

`VAL | true`

**4. Attempt to update value using same conversion in UPDATE**

```
update XWAREHOUSES
set XMLTYPE(cdata) = 
    updatexml(XMLTYPE(cdata),'/Warehouse/WaterAccess/text()','false')
where msd_id = 1;
```

**5. This returns the error:
`SQL Error: ORA-00927: missing equal sign`

Comment: I think set XMLTYPE(cdata) =  should be set cdata = and assuming the right side of the set will be implicitly converted to CLOB. Give a try and let me know.

Comment: Also is PL/SQL an option to consider?

Comment: If I remove XMLTYPE in the SET, but leave it in the XMLUPDATE, I get `SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CLOB got -
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`.

Comment: If I remove the XMLTYPE on both side i get:
`SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

Comment: Do you mean is writing some form of a stored proc an option here instead of a direct update?

Comment: yes in a pl/sql begin ... end block things will be a lot easier with the convertion from clob to xmltype and back with a final update of the clob. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved this 2 different ways, both basically the same way, but one is query and one is a script.

### Solution 1

load the data as xmltype, then perform xml operation, and finally convert back to clob before executing the update

```
update xwarehouses
set cdata =
(
  select updatexml(xmltype(cdata),'/Warehouse/WaterAccess/text()','true').getclobval() 
  from xwarehouses where msd_id = 1
)
where msd_id = 1;
commit;
```

### Solution 2

This isn't the tidiest version, as I could probably make due with the query from **solution 1** and just add some variables. This essentially does the same thing with all the conversions listed out.

```
DECLARE
  p_msg_id number := 1;
  p_cdata xmltype;  
  p_value varchar(50) :='false';
  p_data clob;

BEGIN
  select cdata into p_data from xwarehouses;
  p_cdata := xmltype(p_data);
  select updatexml(p_cdata,'/Warehouse/WaterAccess/text()',p_value) into p_cdata from dual;
  p_data := p_cdata.getclobval();
  update xwarehouses
  set cdata = p_data
  where msd_id = p_msg_id;
  commit;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

From ORACLE 11

> All Oracle SQL functions for updating XML data are deprecated. Oracle
>   recommends that you use XQuery Update instead. These are the
>   deprecated XML updating functions:

[Migration from Oracle Functions for Updating XML Data to XQuery Update](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/app_depr_upd.htm#GUID-8DFBDD92-2FD8-4F30-8B26-6E5FC22090F7)

Example:

```
UPDATE xwarehouses SET cdata =
  xmlserialize(document XMLQuery('copy $tmp := $source  modify
            (for $i in $tmp/Warehouse/WaterAccess/text()  
             return replace value of node $i
                    with "false") 
            return $tmp'
           PASSING xmltype(cdata) as "source"  RETURNING CONTENT))
  WHERE cdata IS NOT NULL;
```